# TypeScript. Не получается присвоить тип переменной

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
  const createObligation = useCallback(
    data => {
      setIsShowNewObligation(false);
      dispatch(createObligationThunk(data));
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  const updateObligation = useCallback(
    (data): void => {
      setInEdit(false);
      dispatch(updateObligationThunk(data));
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

        const onSubmit: any = item._isNew ? createObligation : updateObligation;
        const onCancel: any = item._isNew ? () => setIsShowNewObligation(false) : () => setInEdit(false);
```

Мне нужно прописать тип для двух констант. Если я пишу
`const onSubmit: void = ...` 
, то появляется ошибка :

> TS2322: Type '(data: any) => void' is not assignable to type 'void'.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4):

В ошибке указан тип, который имеет присваиваемое значение

```
(data: any) => void
```

именно его и надо было указывать для переменной:

```
const onSubmit:  (data: any) => void = ...
```

Сейчас же идет попытка объявить переменную с типом `void`.